# error in nvcc using emulation mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, nvcc

When trying to build an example from the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK using Visual Studio 2008, I get this weird error:

```
"C:\CUDA\bin\nvcc.exe"    -arch sm_10 -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin" -deviceemu -D_DEVICEEMU   -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi   /MTd  " -I"C:\CUDA\include" -I"../../common/inc" -maxrregcount=32  --compile -o "Debug\matrixMul.cu.obj" "c:\Documents and Settings\All Users.SYSROOT\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\src\matrixMul\matrixMul.cu" 
nvcc fatal   : Could not open input file C:\DOCUME~1\Murali_Krishna05\Local Settings\Temp/tmpxft_000008cc_00000000-1
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing the environmental varialble "TEMP=%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp" by "TEMP=%SystemRoot%\TEMP".

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/398886/cuda-programming-and-performance/nvcc-could-not-open-input-file-nvcc-dies-on-something-in-temp/1) old bug in the NVIDIA VS2008 integration. We've had to do all of the following 3 steps to solve it.

1. `set TEMP=%SystemRoot%\TEMP`
2. check and potentially`set PATH=` to avoid any quotation marks `"` which are anyway superfluous (*and dangerous!*). Just delete them: individual directories are separated by semicolon `;` and spaces are not a problem
3. (assuming you have VS2008 installed in the default location and target the usual Win64 and Win32 platforms) replace just the first pair of parentheses `(` and `)` in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat"` and `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"`

Example for step 3:

Replace

```
@if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" (
    set "PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin;%PATH%"
    set "INCLUDE=%WindowsSdkDir%include;%INCLUDE%"
    set "LIB=%WindowsSdkDir%lib;%LIB%"
)
```

by

```
@if "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" @goto :SKIP_SET_SDK
set "PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin;%PATH%"
set "INCLUDE=%WindowsSdkDir%include;%INCLUDE%"
set "LIB=%WindowsSdkDir%lib;%LIB%"
:SKIP_SET_SDK
```